# How to transform nonlinear model to linear?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, linear-regression

I'm ananlyzing a dataset, and I know that the data should follow a power model:

```
y = a*x**b
```

I transformed it to linear by taking logarithms:

```
ln(y) = ln(a) + b* ln(x)
```

However, the problems arised on adding a trend line to the plot

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.mstats.linregress(x_ln, y_ln)
yy = np.exp(intercept)*wetarea_x**slope
plt.scatter(wetarea_x, arcgis_wtrshd_x, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(wetarea_x, yy, color = 'green')
```

[image]

This is what I get with this code.
How to modify the code, so that the trend line on the plot would be correct?

Comment: How did you get multiple regression lines?  Please check (i.e. print) your input and output arguments.  I suspect there's a dimensionality problem here.

Comment: both x_ln and y_ln are (667,1) arrays. yy is the same. linear regression parameters are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your green strange plot is what you get when you do a line plot in `matplotlib`, with the `x` values unsorted. It's a line plot, but it connects by lines *(x, y)* pairs jumping right and left (in your specific case, it looks like back to near the x-origin). That gives these strange patterns.

You don't have this problem with the blue plot, because it's a scatter plot.

Try calling the plot after sorting both arrays according to the indices of the first using [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), say

```
wetarea_x[np.argsort(wetarea_x)]
```

and

```
yy[np.argsort(wetarea_x)]
```

Comment: I guess I have a dimensionality problem as Prune noticed, because after sorting arrays I got the following error: ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D

Comment: And wetarea_x[np.argsort(wetarea_x)] has size (667,1,1)

Comment: So can you first reshape them? Something like `z = z.reshape((667, ))`, to reshape `z` to a 1d array.